# Find matching data in two different spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am a realtor with two spreadsheets. One is a list of approx 250 names and addresses of people for whom I have phone numbers but no info about home equity.  I have another spreadsheet of about 1400 names of people I have names and addresses and home equity but no phone numbers.  I want to find the 250 people with phone numbers on the list of the 1400.  I don't want to remove duplicates - I actually want to eliminate every non duplicated addresses. How do I do this?

Comment: What did you try so far ? Can you post any formula or macro you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

So you have a list A with 250 people (Name, Address, Phone) and another list B with 1400 (Name, Address, Equity).

From what I understand, you want to match all the 250 people and try to find them in list B. You can do this easily using `VLOOKUP` (or vertical lookup) which looks for a given value in another list and displays that if found. And once a match is found, you can also make it get the details of home equity or addresses from list B, and add it alongside details from list A.

Here's an example which assumes sheet1 and sheet2 for lists A and B respectively and column order as mentioned above. This formula will fetch all equity information for the 250 folks based on sheet 2. This specific one will have to be pasted in cell D1, and then dragged to fill column D. Note that the comparison here is based on Names.

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1, Sheet2!$A$1:$A$1400, 3, FALSE)
```

The 4 arguments:

- The lookup value or the item to be searched (Name from List A)
- The table array or where to find the item in (List B)
- The column index to be returned in case of match (3 stands for Home Equity)
- FALSE stands for exact match

Here's more on [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx).